# Integral $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4+a^{2}b^{2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> How to evaluate the following integral $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4+a^{2}b^{2}}dx?$$ where $0<a<b$

I observed that we can change the variable in a way that simplifies the expression but the coefficients of the integral becomes extremely ugly.

With the substitution $t=x^2$ it ends being $$\frac{1}{4}\int_{a^2}^{b^2} \frac{\ln t}{t^{2}+a^{2}b^{2}}dt=\frac14\int_{a^2}^{b^2}\frac{\ln t}{(t-ab)^2-2abt}dt$$

Comment: The integral in the photo does not appear to be the same as the integral in the title.

Comment: It is. $x=\frac{(x^{2})'}{2}$.

Comment: If $t=x^2$ then shouldn't the limits in the second integral be $a^2$ and $b^2$?

Comment: Yes indeed. I correct it now.

Comment: For the record this question is connected to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122728/evaluate-int-26-frac-lnx-1x22x2dx and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946085/integral-of-the-form-int-ab-frac-lncdxpxdx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$I=\int_ {a}^{b}\frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4+a^{2}b^{2}}dx\overset{x^2=t}=\frac14 \int_{a^2}^{b^2} \frac{\ln t}{t^2+a^2b^2}dt $$
Let's get rid of that ugly denominator by doing a $t=y(ab)$:
$$I=\frac{ab}4\int_\frac{a}{b}^\frac{b}{a}\frac{\ln(yab)}{a^2b^2(y^2+1) }dy=\frac{1}{4ab}\int_\frac{a}{b}^\frac{b}{a}\frac{\color{blue}{\ln y+\ln(ab)}}{y^2+1 }dy$$
And now one might notice the simmetry directly. Substituting $y=\frac{1}{x}$ gives:
$$\frac{1}{4ab}\int_\frac{a}{b}^\frac{b}{a}\frac{\color{red}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\ln(ab)}}{x^2+1 }dx$$
Adding the red and blue integral simiplifies quite nice the logarithm:
$$\require{cancel} 2I=\frac{1}{4ab}\int_\frac{a}{b}^\frac{b}{a}\frac{\color{red}{\cancel{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\ln(ab)}+\color{blue}{\cancel{\ln x+}\ln(ab)}}{x^2+1}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{\ln (ab)}{4ab}\int_\frac{a}{b}^\frac{b}{a}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{\ln (ab)}{4ab}\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a} -\arctan \frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Comment: This is pure beauty ! $\to +1$

Comment: What do you mean by "notice the s[y]mmetry directly"? I can't seem to see it directly. Unless you mean the bounds on the integral are reciprocals, so you tried the reciprocal substitution...

Comment: Yes, the fact that the bounds and the polynomial remains invariant after using the reciprocal substitution so only the logarithm changes is all what is it here. And it's not hard to notice before actually trying the substitution that $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ (same for the bounds), that is way I said *notice the symmetry directly*.

Comment: Of course, this is the easiest case and for the harder ones such as this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122750/515527 it's not easy to notice the symmetry directly and one must actually do some work.